# Angular Firestore permission with OR statement and doc related auth data

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

Trying to get Angular Firestore running using angularfire2. In my firebase rules configuration I've got a OR statement and I'm able to read all documents with `published == true` but I can't get the `isAdmin()` flag to true and read all documents. My firestore server **rules** look like

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    function isAdmin() {
      return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.admin == true;
    }

    match /myDocs/{myDoc} {
      allow read: if resource.data.published == true || isAdmin();
    }
  }
}
```

I also tested `/users/$(request.auth.uid)` as path with no success. The public client side query for the `published==true` flag looks like

```js
const myDocsCollection = this.db.collection('myDocs', ref => ref.where('published', '==', true));
const myDocs = myDocsCollection.snapshotChanges();
```

And works pretty well. But I can't get the auth-based request working since it does not depend on the `resource` in the rules. The docs are pretty weak for this case.

I tried to use a `.where('auth', '==', firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)` but that's not working and it doesn't make that much sense. Also tested just the `isAdmin()` statement without anything else and without a `where` clause. It always returns *insufficient permissions*. Do I have to pass in the auth data manually or does firebase include the auth data by default?

[image: Firestore users database]

This is a snippet of the users database and the key definitely equals the users `uid`. In the admin service I request the data with

```js
get(): Observable<MyDoc[]> {
  console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser); // returns user with correct uid
  const myDocsCollection = this.db.collection('myDocs');
  return myDocs = myDocsCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(/* do some mapping, apply docid */);
}
```

Comment: Try removing the arguments from your `isAdmin` function. Other than that it looks like a rule I have, so it should work

Comment: Thanks, it works! Another question: How can I filter by published flag, even when I'm authorized?

Comment: Oh damn sorry, its not working. Thought about wrong flag state in database.